# Count the Number of Elements with the same Value in a Row?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Let's assume I have the following data structure:

```js
const Table = [
  [
    {
      "id": "258ce34d-cba6-44a8-bdb9-e436d18701aa",
      "seat": 1,
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "60adc321-c7e3-4d34-963a-e09dc53345d0",
      "seat": 2,
      "group": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "seat": "empty",
      "group": 0
    },
    {
      "seat": "empty",
      "group": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "c8c3c973-351b-4314-8096-a6d12c7b01fb",
      "seat": 5,
      "group": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "1c256b45-b3f3-49cc-b7e4-29967594c4fb",
      "seat": 6,
      "group": 3
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "seat": "empty",
      "group": "empty"
    },
    {
      "seat": 0,
      "group": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "63469f95-7deb-483c-ad7d-cf0cbdc191b1",
      "seat": 9,
      "group": 5
    },
    {
      "id": "e77c8fb3-2e0b-43f7-a9ca-1bbd8143ba59",
      "seat": 10,
      "group": 5
    }
  ]
]
```

It is an array that represents a table in a restaurant. In this array there are other arrays representing the groups of guests.

As you can see there are two free slots at the table.

The task now is to write a function that calculates how many seats are free in a row. Input is this array and output should be a number. So in this case MaxFreeSeatsinRow(Table) => 2

For example, if a group of 4 people arrives, there are enough seats but not in one row.

Does anyone have an idea how to calculate this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is so vague, What exactly do you want and what should be the expected output?

Comment: Input is this array and output should be a number. So in this case MaxFreeSeatsinRow(Table) => 2

Comment: What did you try so far, can you show your progres?

Comment: Use the `map` and `filter` methods on the array.

Comment: Still not clear because what does `2` represents, `2` objects whose `seats` and `group` are `empty` or there are `2` total objects in an array `Table` whose `seats` and `group` is empty

Comment: It's not so much about the specific data structure, let's say I have the following array: [1,1,1,0,0,01,1,1,0,0,]

Now I want to know/calculate how many times the zero occurs in a row, in this case 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, this is really just a matter of flattening the structure to an array of seats and then finding the longest streak of empty seats.

We can write a general-purpose `longestStreak` function which accepts a predicate function and returns a function which accepts a list of elements, and then tests each element against that predicate, updating the length of the current streak and possibly the maximum value when it matches, and resetting the current streak to zero when it doesn't.

Our main function, `canSeat` accepts a Table, and supplies to `longestStreak` a predicate which tests if a seat has value of `0` or `"empty"` (**note**: do you really want to support *both*?) and then supplies to the resulting function an extract of the Table selecting all the seats in it.

```js
const longestStreak = (pred) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce (
    ({max, curr}, x) => pred (x) 
      ? {max: curr >= max ? curr + 1 : max, curr: curr + 1} 
      : {max, curr: 0}
    , {max: 0, curr: 0}
  ) .max

const canSeat = (table) => longestStreak 
  (s => s == 0 || s == "empty") 
  (table .flatMap (groups => groups .map (g => g .seat)))

const Table = [[{id: "258ce34d-cba6-44a8-bdb9-e436d18701aa", seat: 1, group: 1}, {id: "60adc321-c7e3-4d34-963a-e09dc53345d0", seat: 2, group: 1}], [{seat: "empty", group: 0}, {seat: "empty", group: 0}], [{id: "c8c3c973-351b-4314-8096-a6d12c7b01fb", seat: 5, group: 3}, {id: "1c256b45-b3f3-49cc-b7e4-29967594c4fb", seat: 6, group: 3}], [{seat: "empty", group: "empty"}, {seat: 0, group: 0}], [{id: "63469f95-7deb-483c-ad7d-cf0cbdc191b1", seat: 9, group: 5}, {id: "e77c8fb3-2e0b-43f7-a9ca-1bbd8143ba59", seat: 10, group: 5}]]

console .log (canSeat (Table))
```

Comment: great work! This is exactly the solution I was looking for! Unfortunately, you learn something like this in no book or tutorial.  It is still difficult for me to come up with such solutions myself. Do you have any tips on how I can get better at it? 

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have no overall great advice as to how to come up with solutions. Mostly it's a matter of experience.  You have to keep doing it, and learning from what you've done. What worked? What didn't? What little tools or techniques look useful for future problems? When you find such, refine them until they seem to have reached their essence. Relentlessly break the problems down into pieces until each one seems manageable. Here, I started with your "I have the following array: [1,1,1,0,0,01,1,1,0,0,] Now I want to know/calculate how many times the zero occurs in a row, in this case 3 times." 1/3

Comment: That made me think from two ends.  How do I achieve that intermediate format?  How do I then count the consecutive zeros? The first problem is fairly easy. I know I can do it with `flatMap`, without too much work. The second one takes some more thinking. I abstract early. What if it's not zero I'm looking for but an arbitrary value? What if it's not just one value but many (say `0` and `"empty"`)? Pretty quickly I realized I wanted a predicate. Here experience tells me that `reduce` will work. A `for` or `while` loop would too, but I prefer `reduce`. 2/3

Comment: At that point, it was just a matter of writing the `longestStreak` function. An experienced person might write it more quickly than a less experienced one, and might write nicer code, but the problem is not hard. And I've hit the magic point where none of the pieces are hard, and I can just put them together. A big part of this is the early abstraction. Many problems turn out simpler if you think of them in terms of abstraction. Using a callback with the predicate meant I didn't have to think about `0` or `"empty"` in coding the core function. And now this is a reusable tool in my toolkit. 3/3

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to know of the number of free seats per nested array?

If so, I think it can be pretty straightforward using a functional approach:

```js
const freeSeats = Table.map(row => {
  return row.filter(place => place.seat === "empty").length
})

// freeSeats = [0, 2, 0, 2, 0]
```

Then it's easy to get the maximum grouped seats:

```js
Math.max(...freeSeats)
```

Comment: OP's post is a bit incomplete, but the q is "how many seats are free in a row." (key: in a row), so, Math.max([0,2,2,0]) gives `2`, when the answer there is `4`.

Comment: Well, true, but when taking in account the output he expects (added in the comments of the question), then it seems he wants the max free seats in a single group. But yeah, the question is not very clear regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I promise to formulate my questions better in the future.